# Creating a FaceBook Like Button for C# Winforms Desktop Application

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I want to link my winforms application to Facebook fanpage,So that a +1 is added when the user clicks the Like button on the Form .How can do it in C# winforms.Is it possible by invoking a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get some LIKE button code: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ it will give you a few options, then you have a choice of delivery formats - choose `IFRAME`.

you'll get something that looks like this:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webbod.info&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

You are only interested in the `src` and the dimensions.

In your winforms application you can host a webbrowser control size it to the dimensions and point it at the src - this will give you an embedded facebook like button.

**Facebook allows people to Like URLs, so you'll need to provide one** - in my example it's www.webbod.info, but anything should do and by varying the `href` part of the `src` url you can let people like any part of the application.

Comment: it was a typo - you can't embed a webbrowser control in a webform - the idea is to provide a portal to load contents of the iframe.

Comment: Is there any way i can do it with the URL Only by using Process.Start(URL) Without embedding the browser,as a pc which has no internet connection will cause an error page to be displayed in the embedded browser